# Microsoft Visual Studuo не генерит файлы App.g.cs App.g.i.cs при работе с WPF PrismApplication .NET Core

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, prism

В Microsoft Visual Studio (VS) 16.5.4, создаю пустой шаблон проекта Prism Blank App(.NET Core). Сразу высвечиваются ошибки при компиляции связанные с файлом App.xaml.cs

> Ошибка    CS0115  '"App.CreateShell()": не найден метод, пригодный для переопределения.
>   Ошибка  CS0115  '"App.RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry)": не найден метод, пригодный для переопределения.
>   Ошибка  CS0103  Имя "Container" не существует в текущем контексте.  BlankCoreApp1

В самом App.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class App
```

То есть нет наследования от PrismApplication. Ранее VS генерировала файл \obj\Debug\App.g.cs, где было:

```
public partial class App : PrismApplication
```

Поэтому не было и этих ошибок. А сейчас этого файла нет, хотя в свойствах файла **app.xaml** стоит - **Действие при сборке - Определение приложения** (по моему мнению это означает - должна генерировать файл приложения). Почему VS перестала генерировать файл App.g.cs? Как это исправить?

**app.xaml:**

```
<prism:PrismApplication x:Class="BlankCoreApp6.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BlankCoreApp6"
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/" >
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</prism:PrismApplication>
```

**app.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class App
    {
        protected override Window CreateShell()
        {
            return Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
        }

        protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Обычно, в WPF, такое бывает в момент наличия серьезной ошибки в XAML. Проверьте тщательно их, скорей всего это решит проблему.

Comment: Я вставил в вопрос код app.xaml и app.xaml.cs Ошибок в них я не вижу. Дело еще в том, что перестали собираться примеры Prism, которые ранее собирались без проблем. Пишет - не найдена точка входа - метод Main (это и понятно, так как в сгенерированном App.g.cs находится Main). Перестало собираться после очередного обновления VS. Я обращался в MS, после этого пришло еще одно обновление, но ошибка не ушла.

Comment: Еще хотел добавить - такая же проблема с проектом WPF .NET Core - так же не создается файл с точкой входа Main. То есть VS для проекта .NET Core не хочет генерить файл App.g.cs. Может у меня что-то со Студией? Но я уже ее сбрасывал - ничего не изменилось.

Answer (score 0):

Написал об этом баге в Микрософт. Через месяц вышло обновление. Ошибка исчезла.

Comment: Не могли бы вы добавить в ответ чуть больше деталей.